# How to access Rich Text Field Image outside SalesForce?

Tags: apex, lightning

I pass the **rich text field** to the external system through the Rest API. When the external system clicks on the URL, I will be prompted to log in to salesforce. Is there any way to skip the login of salesforce and display the image directly?

I searched for relevant information and thought it was feasible.

**example：**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143107/how-to-access-rich-text-field-image-outside-salesforce

But there is no more detailed description. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After my attempts, I found a solution.

1. Create a site and in the "Public Access Settings" of the site, open the data permissions of the access object to the site profile.

[image]
[image]
2. Replace the Org URL path in the rich text field with the site URL.

Such as: src="https://smartsocial--cpcs--c.documentforce.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=701p0000000IWbc&feoid=00Np0000003zxfX&refid=0EMp00000009HnE"

Change to: **http://cpcs-smartsocial.cs31.force.com/AccessImage**/servlet/rtaImage?eid=701p0000000IWbc&feoid=00Np0000003zxfX&refid=0EMp00000009HnE

Comment: `Update `  Now need to add sharing rules to site users.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the image in a document instead and mark it as an **Externally available image**. You can then right click on the image to copy the publicly available url. It is generally in this format - https://jitendercoolguy-dev-ed--c.ap15.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=0159000000D0x2f&oid=00D90000000x5b3.

Just replace the id paramter with the document Id and the oid parameter with the org Id.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions here didn't work for me. I ended up rewriting the urls in the rich text on the fly when returning them from my api. In a manner so that they refer to my api which I use as image proxy through this SF API endpoint with an integration user: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_rich_text_image_retrieve.htm

```
private void rewriteImageUrls(RichTextRecord richTextRecord) {
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(richTextRecord.getBody());
    doc.select("img").forEach(imgElement -> {
        try {
            URL originalUrl = new URL(imgElement.absUrl("src"));
            String newUrl = appEnv.getBackendUrl() + "/api/v1/rich_text_records/" + richTextRecord.getSfid() + "/image?refid="+ UrlUtils.getQueryMap(originalUrl.getQuery()).get("refid");
            imgElement.attr("src", newUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    richTextRecord.setBody(doc.outerHtml());
}
```

Far from ideal but it works!